# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation when building solution

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012, build

When I try to build my solution on Visual Studio 2012 this error pops up for 3 different projects. I tried restarting my PC, building the cleaning the solution and rebuilding again but it didn't work. All my extensions are up to date, I tried googling for a solution but I can't find one. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I just had to uninstall Python Tools for VS 2012 and the errors just went away. I was building the PythonTools project.